# Copy files based on release or debug build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

I am making some changes in my csproj file so when I build debug it will copy a set of debug files and when I build release it will copy a set of release files.

The Start of the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
...
<FlexNetInput></FlexNetInput>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
...
<FlexNetInput>"..\..\..\..\utilities\FlexNet\Debug\Native\"</FlexNetInput>
</PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <FlexNetInput>"..\..\..\..\utilities\FlexNet\Release\Native\"</FlexNetInput>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

At the end of the csproj this is what I have:

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <!-- Copy Native DGI DLL's -->
    <CreateItem Include="..\..\..\..\utilities\dgi\DgiNative\**\*.*">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="NativeDgiFiles" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(NativeDgiFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(NativeDgiFiles->'$(OutputPath)\Native\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
    <!-- Copy Native FlexNet DLL's -->
    <CreateItem Include="'$(FlexNetInput)'**\*.*">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="NativeReleaseFlexNetFiles" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(NativeReleaseFlexNetFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(NativeReleaseFlexNetFiles->'$(OutputPath)\Native\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

The copy of the dgi file works fine, but because the location of the FlexNet file is different depending on if it is release or debug I cant get it to work.

The error I am getting is:
Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(Filename)". The item metadata "%(Filename)" cannot be applied to the path "'"........\utilities\FlexNet\Debug\Native\"***.*'". Illegal characters in path.

I don't think I am using the properties right, any ideas?

Solved, This is how I got it working:

```
<CreateItem Include="..\..\..\..\utilities\FlexNet\$(Configuration)\Native\**\*.*">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="NativeFlexNetFiles" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(NativeFlexNetFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(NativeFlexNetFiles->'$(OutputPath)\Native\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

Comment: When you say you "can't get it to work", what do you mean? What does it do or not do? Any errors, or does it just not copy anything? Do you need the "s around the path in FlexNetInput?

Comment: I am getting an error. I added it near the bottom of the original question.

Comment: any reason you use CreateItem instead of just an ItemGroup with e.g. `<FlexNetInput Include="..\..\..\..\utilities\FlexNet\$(Configuration)\Native\**\*.*"/>` ?

Comment: I will look up how to use it

Comment: @stijn, that works and allowed me to fix my problem. I was just over complicating things. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days you should probably never need `CreateItem` [anymore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x.aspx). ItemGroups can be placed inside targets, and will be evaluated when the target runs. Also since your output directory has the same name as your Configuration you can use it as a property. Together this gives

```
<ItemGroup>
  <NativeReleaseFlexNetFiles Include=
    "..\..\..\..\utilities\FlexNet\$(Configuration)\Native\**\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

in your AfterBuild target.